# How to view SSL Certificates in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, certificate

I would like to see the certificates of my outgoing and incoming servers in thunderbird for each of my accounts. How would I do that ? The certificate manager doesn't seem to be of any help and doesn't show the certificates used by my servers (Edit > Preferences > Advanced > Certificates > Manage Certificates)

Comment: What OS are you on? Mine are shown in the "servers" tab of the Manage Certificates page.

Comment: @pbhj: That tab usually collects only exceptions that you have manually approved; it does not cache CA-validated certificates.

Comment: @pbhj linux mint release 17, thunderbird 60.6.1)

Comment: Doesn’t look like this is possible in Thunderbird. Would a command-line tool (`openssl`) be acceptable for you?

Comment: @DanielB only if the results are always the same, i.e, thunderbird validation of the certificate is the same as openssl. I've seen cases where the certificate is valid on one system but not on older systems (eg. windows XP. Yes, some systems are still running that).

Comment: E.g the ACME ISRG X3 root certificate that was signed by DST Root CA X3, which expired in late 2021, making all letsencrypt certificates invalid until you manually re-installed the new ISRG X3 self-signed certificate on the host.

Comment: Hm, that won’t work then I guess. Firefox (and probably Thunderbird) ships its own trusted CA database, which may or may not be the same. You can see the certificate, but you cannot verify its trust status.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that TLS is the successor of SSL. Maybe next time you want to ask about TLS and not deprecated SSL.

It's possible to download the server's certificate in the terminal. The command is:

```
openssl s_client -connect server:port
```

Maybe you have to install openssl before:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
```

See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37101/how-to-display-servers-tls-certificate-details-in-terminal) post for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Using Thunderbird, navigate to Edit > Preferences > Advanced > Certificates > Manage Certificates
2. Using the "Certificate Manager" window, click on this "Servers" horizontal tab
3. Using this "Servers" horizontal tab, you are able to view or delete certificate
   [image: Screenshot]

---

Per user1686, this "Servers" horizontal tab collects only exceptions that you have manually approved. It does not cache CA-validated certificates. This is normal.

If you need to view CA-validated certificates, the other steps below are one easy and free way to do this.

Steps to view CA-validated certificates:

1. Using your favourite internet browser, such as Firefox 91, go to the URL hosting the mail server certificate. For example, go to [https://mailbox.org](https://mailbox.org/)
2. Using Firefox, click on the small lock button. Which is located on the left side of the URL field.
3. Click on the ~"Secured connection" line
4. Click on ~"More information" line
5. Click on ~"View certificate" button

Comment: Firefox won’t show the certificates that are used for non-HTTP connections (POP3, IMAP, SMTP).

Comment: To paraphrase @DanielB said, it is possible to have different certificates for POP3, IMAP, SMTP and HTTPS servers. (the HTTPS server certificate might be different from the mail server's)